# Ionic 3 Splash Screen goes white when only theres no network or internet in the mobile device

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an **Ionic 3 App** developing and testing it in a **Android device**. After the `splash screen` has showed and loaded on the **screen** The **screen** goes **white** when there is **no internet connection** on the **device**.

But when there is **internet connection** or network **connectivity** the app successfully loaded without any **whitescreen** after the splash **screen**.

I have **installed** all my SDK versions in my **Android Studio** from **Lollipop** to **Latest** but I don't think this has an effect on this right?

Any thoughts on this?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have used any browser page in your screen where you required internet connection ?

Comment: @CodeChanger whay do u mean **browser page?** in the app of my device or is it the browser of the device like chrome and etc..

Comment: Do you have special settings in config like:  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
 <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
 <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
 <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />

Comment: @SergeyRudenko yes I do have.

Comment: in app you have anything like required Internet which stops loading without internet in starting app ?\

Comment: @CodeChanger sorry. I can't understand it. Do u mean I have a function that requires connection? The only thing that my app initialize is when the root page is my tabs page which has an ajax api call get request to a server to render some data.

Comment: thats what i am asking you need to check network connection if your device connected to network call that  api or else show some alert to user that device not connected to network.

Comment: @CodeChanger thank you so much. I solved it using the plugin ionic network